# Internal compiler error because of semicolon after class

Tags: c++, g++

I've wrote small header file with class.

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

class Game{
    private:
        bool isRunning;
    public:
        bool IsRunning() const;
};

#endif
```

When I try to compile it I get

```
c:\Users\MainUser\Desktop\cpp_tests\src\Game.h:9:2: internal compiler error: in gt_pch_note_object, at ggc-common.c:276
 };
  ^
```

Deleting doesn't help.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are PCHs involved?

Comment: Which version of GCC/MinGW are you using? Did you try update it? Googling the message `gt_pch_note_object, at ggc-common.c:276` gave me multiple bug reports, that were marked as fixed.

Comment: I don't know what PCH is

Comment: I installed the last version of MinGW yesterday

Comment: Precompiled header

Comment: I compile all files, including headers, if that's what you mean.

Comment: If you don't know what this means you probably are not using it.

Comment: @Sofon Can you run `g++ --version` in your console and give us the output?

Comment: @drescherjm Unlikely, yes. But some IDE Creators  seem to think, it is an good idea to have their starter templates to include PCHs. Could be one of those cases.

Comment: g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

Comment: sorry, it seems not to be the last version. I will try to update and report the result.

Comment: ICE is a bug in the compiler. It often is triggered by something wrong in your code but not always. I would suggest upgrading your compiler first.

Comment: Evil code:  member variable name having same name as member function.  Please differentiate between them (using different letters or names).   The C++ language allows you to have at 32 characters for function names and variable names. (They can be longer, but the first 32 must be unique).

Comment: I've installed the newest version of the compiler and it works now

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `isRunning` and `IsRunning` are two different identifiers. I'm not a big fan of differentiating identifiers only by case, but the compiler shouldn't care. (I can imagine it triggering a compiler bug, but that seems unlikely.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest version of MinGW solved the problem